# Back-to-basic question regarding OpAmp, its input and output information

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

I am doing literature research about Transimpedance Amplifier (TIA) architecture and designs.
What I know for sure are its input is current, its output is voltage and it has low input and output impedance.

But I found some [publications](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7572106) that use OTA+Resistive feedback to form a TIA.
It makes me question some fundamentals understanding that I have so far.

[image: OTA+Resistive feedback]

Questions:

1. Is the topology like this VCVS(Opamp) or VCCS(OTA)?
   There is [this](https://www.edaboard.com/threads/what-is-difference-between-ota-and-op-amp.99332/) discussion as well but it did not give a conclusion.

[image]

Razavi also referred the following Cascode Op Amp circuit as OTA.
[image]
[image]

2. If I have Current Amp and I dump this current into a resistor, does it make the circuit to become TIA? I do not think so, because we need to consider the impedance also at the input and output port.